# Should I write $i$ before or after the imaginary part?

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question

Should I write complex numbers as $a+ib$ or $a+bi$? Maybe there are certain cases where I should write it one way and other cases where I should write it the other way. What do you think?

Comment: In engjneerjng, we write $2 + j3$. In math texts, I usually see $2\pi i$, and in the early chapters of introductory complex analysis texts, $a + bi$ is pretty common. However, I've also seen $z = x + iy$, so ymmw.

Comment: I think that you can write it above and top too, why only left or right? Nah, joking, it is irrelevant where you put $i$, left or right, because the multiplication is commutative in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Agree with @Masacroso, but just to add, sometimes it's more convenient to write it on the left. For instance, when the imaginary part is a radical, since $a + i\sqrt{b}$ is a lot nicer to look at than $a + \sqrt{b}i$

Comment: Just to add a note to the comment of @Ed_4434: if you put the $i$ in the left it is "symmetric" to the writing of the function $\Im (x)$ that is the imaginary part of $x$. In general it is better to write it in the left, for clarity.

Comment: In addition to Ed's answer, in case of a radical it is safer to put the $i$ upfront due to handwriting issues. More than once I have seen that students put the "roof" of the radical sign slightly too long and it kind of looks like that the $i$ is looking for shade under the radical, which is not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 10):

It's really a matter of style, but I typically see integer factors written first, then other real constants, then $i$, then variables.  Thus you might have $2\pi inx$.

Answer (score 2):

If the imaginary part is a number, say 2, clearly it is better to write it as $2i$ rather than $i2$.

If the imaginary part is a "variable" or represented by a letter, then it is up to your personal preference. $x+iy$, $e^{i\theta}$ seems to be more common than $x+yi$, $e^{\theta i}$ though.