# $\pi i$ or $i \pi$?

Tags: notation, convention

Is the usage of either $\pi i$ or $i \pi$ technically correct compared to the other? I have seen both used frequently by many sources.

Edit: I understand the two are equal. I am asking whether there is any convention which makes it preferable to write either $\pi i$ or $i \pi$, in the same vein as why we write $2x$ and not $x2$.

Comment: I prefer $i\pi$. $\pi i$ seems a bit weird, although I've seen it.

Comment: $i\pi$ and $\pi i$ are interchangeable, but $2\pi i$ seems to always be $2\pi i.$  I tend to go with $\pi i$

Comment: They’re equal because multiplication is commutative

Comment: I learned the Euler identity as $e^{i\pi}+1=0$.

Comment: Whichever typograhic norm you wish others to adhere to... is exactly what you may write. I'm not sure I could tell you that I've consistently used one over the other in the case of $i\pi$ versus $\pi i$ (although the former is nicer to type in $\TeX$). In general, if $a+bi$ has a "complicated expression" for $b$, I tend to write $i$ in the front.

Comment: Here are my thoughts: With imaginary numbers, I always put $\mathrm i$ as close to the front for recognisability , as in $z=x+\mathrm iy$. For this reason I imagine $\rm e^{\rm iπ}+1=0$ is frequently written in that order. However, complex numbers and circles are closely connected, so factors of $2π$ show up frequently, leading to coefficients like $2π\rm i$ rather than $2\rm iπ$; for example, $f(a)=\frac1{2π\mathrm i}\int\frac{f(z)\,\mathrm dz}{z-a}$.

Answer (score 2):

They are equal since multiplication over the complex number field is commutative.

$$\pi i = i \pi$$

Edit:

I am not aware of any convention that suggests one is preferable to the others.  Here is another related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2012900/306553).

Comment: Gotta love the technically correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that if you're writing it as a polynomial in $\pi$, then $i \cdot \pi$ makes sense, as we put coefficients on the left as a convention. But otherwise, I do not see any practical advantages of one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

As for me I prefer to write $i \cdot \pi$.